# Dynamically load partial based on controller action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a series of different blocks of HTML that i'd like to load into my partial "_right_column" based on the controller and action.  What is the best way to conditionally load a partial based on the current controller & action, and where should this check occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `controller.controller_name` and `controller.action_name` in your view.

Depending on how big the particular switch statement is, you will probably want to put it in a helper method in application_helper rather than into your partial _right_column.